# Javascript modules with @babel/standalone

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I am trying to use Javascript `import` with @babel/standalone, and I am getting this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

This is my minimal reproducible code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/babel" data-type="module">
            import a from './abc.js';
            console.log(a);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

And `abc.js` file:

```js
export default 567;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I test this and working